# Making sense of build error while running gulp

Tags: gulp

Everytime I run my gulp task, it generates a error on first run. The error is below. When I run it again, it builds without any error.

I am confused, why does it throw an error the first time but not after that.

```
[08:38:08] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/Code/proj2/Gulpfile.js
[08:38:08] Starting 'stylus'...
[08:38:08] Finished 'stylus' after 7.99 ms
[08:38:08] Starting 'copyClientHTML'...
[08:38:08] Finished 'copyClientHTML' after 2.27 ms
[08:38:08] Starting 'clientLint'...
[08:38:08] Starting 'demon'...
[08:38:08] Finished 'demon' after 1.88 ms
[gulp] [nodemon] v1.2.1
[gulp] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[gulp] [nodemon] watching: *.*
[gulp] [nodemon] starting `node server/js/server.js`
[08:38:08] Starting 'watch'...
[08:38:09] Finished 'watch' after 31 ms

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: ENOENT, stat '/Users/jhans/Documents/Code/proj2/client/build/index.html'
```

Including Gulpfile.

```
/*jshint globalstrict: true*/
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
  browserify = require('gulp-browserify'),
  clean = require('gulp-clean'),
  jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
  stylish = require('jshint-stylish'),
  stylus = require('gulp-stylus'),
  del = require('del'),
  nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon'),
  concat = require('gulp-concat');

var paths = {
  client: {
    scripts: 'client/js/**/*.js',
    html: 'client/views/*.html',
    index: 'client/*.html',
    css: 'client/css/*.styl',
    conf: 'client/conf.js'
  },
  server: {
    scripts: 'server/js/**/*.js'
  }

};

// Rerun the task when a file changes
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch(paths.client.css, ['stylus']);
  gulp.watch(paths.client.scripts, ['browserify']);
  gulp.watch([paths.client.html, paths.client.index], ['copyClientHTML']);
  gulp.watch(paths.server.scripts, ['serverLint']);
});


gulp.task('demon', function () {
  nodemon({
    script: 'server/js/server.js',
    ext: 'js',
    env: {
      'NODE_ENV': 'development'
    }
  })
    .on('start', ['watch'])
    .on('change', ['watch'])
    .on('restart', function () {
      console.log('restarted!');
    });
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['build', 'demon']);

gulp.task('build', ['stylus', 'copyClientHTML', 'browserify']);


/********** Building CSS *********/
gulp.task('stylus', function () {

  del(['client/build/css/*']);

  gulp.src(paths.client.css)
    .pipe(stylus())
    .pipe(concat('all.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('client/build/css/'));
});


gulp.task('clientLint', function () {
  return gulp.src([paths.client.scripts])
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter(stylish));
});


gulp.task('serverLint', function () {
  return gulp.src([paths.server.scripts])
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter(stylish));
});


gulp.task('browserify',['clientLint'], function () {

  del(['client/build/js/*']);

  gulp.src('client/js/app.js')
    .pipe(browserify({
      insertGlobals: true,
      debug: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('client/build/js'));
});


gulp.task('copyClientHTML', function () {
  del(['client/build/views/*.*']);
  del(['client/build/index.html']);

  gulp.src(paths.client.html)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('client/build/views'));

  gulp.src(paths.client.index)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('client/build'));

});
```

Comment: What does your gulpfile look like? It's impossible to tell without.

Comment: I'd guess that something depends on that `/Users/jhans/Documents/Code/proj2/client/build/index.html` exists and first run creates that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might come from your `copyClientHTML` task (and potentially some others).

Indeed, you have to know that the `del` module does not run synchronously. So it might delete your files after there were created, and can explain the issue you're experiencing.

I may advice you to create a task dedicated to the cleaning of your files that you can put as dependency of some of your tasks; or better a little function where you can pass a parameter to clean specified folders.

This will ensure you that the cleaning is finished before creating the new files.